# Other or Another

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

I have a question about Quantitative words that I don't understand. Here it is:

```
Q: Istanbul is the biggest city in Turkey and one of the world's major
  cities, with around 6.7 million people in the city.......and......four
  million in the area around it. 
    A. Its own/other 
    B. Themselves/the other 
    C. Alone/others 
    D. One another/ the others 
    E. Itself/ Another
```

The answer is E. Itself/another. But I think it is A. its own/other.
The problem is ''four million'' that it is a number or it is a plural noun? ''Four million people'' is a plural noun, right? SO I think it is ''other four million'' NOT ''Another four million''.
Please explain to me.
Thank you very much.
Take care of yourself ;>

Comment: It is often permitted to drop the noun from the [numeral + noun] string, especially after a parallel usage (There were six boys playing cricket, and three dancing').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is E.

> 6.7 million people in the city itself:

Itself is referring to the city. The city is singular.

> And another 4 million in the area around it.

Another is referring to the 4 million people.

Another in this context is indicating "in addition to".

It's saying: there are this many people in one place, and this many more people in the surrounding area.

"A" wouldn't make sense. "It's own" doesn't fit here. You use "it's own" in a scenario like : "It has its own thing." To indicate ownership of something.

"Other" doesn't make sense either.  "Other" means "not this but that.". E.g. I don't want this one. I want the other one.  Or your could say "The other part of the city has more people."

Comment: You can also use "on its own" to indicate that something is working or is being considered in isolation, or is not receiving outside help.